# Nested jQuery $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Essentially I am tring to write this:

```
var async1 = $.when( a1() ).then(function(){ a2() });
var async2 = $.when( a3() ).then(function(){ a4() });

$.when(async1, async2).then(function(){ 
    console.log("complete");
});
```

But at the moment when a1 and a3 have executed the function considers itself resolved.

I put together the same example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fzR/

Comment: When do you *expect* them to be resolved?

Comment: @ExplosionPills when a1, a2 a3 and a4 are all resolved I would expect the final when to be resolved. If you follow?

Comment: Just guessing... What would happen if you changed it to this? `$.when( a1().then(function(){ a2() }));`

Comment: @ChrisFrancis that did work but ExplosionPills has nailed it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You never actually return the promise objects created by `a2()` and `a4()` from the callback; this effectively returns `null`, which apparently counts as a completion for `$.when` purposes:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fzR/1/

Answer (score 5):

You are throwing away the promise objects that `a2` and `a4` return, essentially passing `undefined` back to the original `when`, which causes it to resolve immediately:

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

Add some returns and it works fine.

```
var async1 = $.when(a1()).then(function(){ return a2(); });
var async2 = $.when(a3()).then(function(){ return a4(); });

$.when(async1, async2).then(function(){
    console.log("complete");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fzR/2/